# I need to find almost duplicates with SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a database where the rows are logically identified by two bits of information:
NAME is a company name. think for example IBM Corporation
LOC is a work site. Think London Development Center.
So the total name would be two fields concatenated: IBM London Development Center (this is not the table key, there's a surrogate identifier on that, but logically this these two columns constitute a unique row.
In this case, IBM can appear on hundreds of records. But there SHOULD be only one IBM London Development Center record (with NAME and LOC concantenated).

But there are NEAR duplicates. Users have appended a string to the end of LOC to denote another use of what should be a single Name-Location, and created duplicate rows.  Like this:

**PAIR ONE**

NAME: IBM
LOC: London Development Center

NAME: IBM
LOC: London Development Center ALT

or **PAIR TWO**

NAME: IBM
LOC: New York Data Center

Name: IBM
LOC: New York Data Center XYZ

I don't need to identify ALL the records with IBM as the NAME (company name), there are hundreds. I just need to find these almost duplicate pairs, where someone has duplicated the LOC name and added something to the end. I need to find BOTH the original record AND the one with the string added. As a pair, so I can have someone work to resolve these duplicates.

It's inside an application, but I've sucked it out into Access for this profiling.  There are about 40,000 rows in the table, and only 1000 or so are these almost dups.

Steve

Comment: Step 1 - fix the application to prevent recurrence.  Step 2 - You will probably have to eyeball the suspect records to determine whether or not they are dupes.  Do something about those that are.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, joining the table with itself, should do it:

```
SELECT c1.[Name], c1.Loc, c2.Loc
FROM Companies c1, Companies c2
WHERE c1.[Name] = c2.[Name]
  AND c1.Loc LIKE c2.Loc & "*"
```

It will probably be slow, but with 40k records it should be manageable.